# Development environment for debugging Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, visual-studio, web

Hi and thanks in advance!

I'm currently using VSCode to learn AngularJS based web applications. I've spent a fair bit of time to no avail trying to create an ideal development setup on my Windows 10 machine. What I'm trying to achieve is a root folder where I can start new projects that I can run on a local web server and debug the Angular code i.e. run the site and put break points in the code and step it through etc.

So something like:

```
-    root folder >
    *    project1 folder >
    *        index.html
    *        scripts folder>
    *        app1.js
    -    project2 folder >
    *        index.html
    *        scripts >
    *        app1.js
```

I've tried using node.js and lite server with npm install and npm start which does run the site on localhost and live changes are reflected but I can debug the code.

Another option I use which does work but seems long winded and over kill is to use MS Visual Web Developer to create a project just for the purpose of running a local web server and then use the external tools to launch VS Code from within Visual Web Dev. I can then use the Chrome debugger to debug directly in VS Code. Whilst this works I wanted to avoid creating a Visual Web Dev project for every new project I want to work on in VS Code.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: To debug AngularJS use the [Developer Console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) in the browser.

Comment: Are you trying to debug code in the browser?  The easiest way for me is just to hit "F12" - that displays the browser debug tools.  I think there is a plugin which can connect the browser back to Node, but I usually just debug in the browser.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to debug in VS Code.